# Best Practice: Handle read-only data with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, flux, redux

I am building an application with React and Redux and I have a question about design.

My application uses React Router. It has a Navigation Bar (on the left) that displays the routes from React Router configuration file with a Material Design Menu.

I would know what is the best practice to handle the static data of this `LeftNav` component.

This data has the following shape:

```
const menuItems = [
  {
    icon: 'home',
    label: 'Home',
    url: '/home',
    withDivider: true,
    access: 'all',
  },
  {
    icon: 'settings',
    label: 'Settings',
    url: '/settings',
    access: 'admin',
  },
  {
    icon: 'power_settings_new',
    label: 'Log Out',
    url: '/logout',
    access: 'user',
  },
];
```

To respect the [smart and dumb component proposal](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0), my `LeftNav` component is dumb and stateless.
I also have a smart component (right now it's just my `AppContainer`) that renders the `LeftNav` component and provides the menuItems array to it via props.

I wonder if I must include this read-only data into my redux state tree. In this case, I would have a constant reducer like this:

```
export default handleActions({}, [
  {
    icon: 'home',
    label: 'Home',
    url: '/home',
    withDivider: true,
    access: 'all',
  },
  {
    icon: 'settings',
    label: 'Settings',
    url: '/settings',
    access: 'admin',
  },
  {
    icon: 'power_settings_new',
    label: 'Log Out',
    url: '/logout',
    access: 'user',
  },
]);
```

**Is it a good practice to have a constant reducer with no action handler?** If not, what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I prefer my reducers to focus on dealing with application / system-wide state.  The configuration in your example would feel more at home living as a constant inside the component which makes use of it (`LeftNav`?)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I agree that reducers should be more focus on application state. In a near future, I want to dynamically generate this configuration (by reading the router configuration) and I am not sure this should take place in a dumb component.

Comment: Don't feel constrained by your choice of framework; just move your logic into a utility / helper function and import that from your dumb component.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not recognizing how your reducer is working. What is `handleActions`?

I think a constant reducer seems like a reasonable solution, but I would implement it by using a default first parameter. Assuming you're using `combineReducers` to scope all your reducers to the part of the state they control, I'd do something like:

```
/* reducers.js */

const menuItemsInitialState = [
  {
    icon: 'home',
    label: 'Home',
    url: '/home',
    withDivider: true,
    access: 'all',
  },
  {
    icon: 'settings',
    label: 'Settings',
    url: '/settings',
    access: 'admin',
  },
  {
    icon: 'power_settings_new',
    label: 'Log Out',
    url: '/logout',
    access: 'user',
  },
];

export function menuItems(state = menuItemsInitialState, _) {
  return state;
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. `handleActions` is provided by [redux-actions](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-actions). It's a tiny function that reduces boilerplate when creating a reducer. I'm calling `combineReducers` with this reducer to create my root reducer.

Answer (score 0):

@Cnode I agree @acjay that **it should be in reducer state**, even without action creators.

I would go one step further and suggest that you should fetch the data after the app loads rather than including the data in your built files. Generally *data does not belong in built files*.

This is because, in the real world this particular set (and others - possibly much larger sets) would be statically available on an API as you probably would want the values configurable by a CMS.

1. Add a static reducer to host this state
2. Fetch the data after the app initialises and then push it on state - meaning you will have at least one action creator.